# Connecting to mongoDB on deployed meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor, deployment, connection-string, mongodb-compass

I recently deployed an app on galaxy using meteor 2.0 and mongo. I deployed using the command `meteor deploy <domain>.au.meteorapp.com --free --mongo` and it gave me the mongo URL below.

`mongodb://<username>:<password>@SG-apgalaxycluster-38734.servers.mongodirector.com:27017,SG-apgalaxycluster-38735.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/<domain>-au-meteorapp-com?replicaSet=RS-apgalaxycluster-0&ssl=true`

I cant seem to access this DB on mongo compass as when I paste the connection string in I simply get an error saying `self signed certificate`

Does anyone know how I can access it?

Comment: is this your database name? `<domain>-au-meteorapp-com`

Comment: If you think this is an issue caused by Galaxy you may actually write an email to their support.

Comment: I believe so @MostafizRahman . Its the same as the website domain name. I dont have a lot of experience with Mongo so dont know how to be sure

Comment: Have you tried ssl=false ?